# Is it possible to monitor all camera activity on Android

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, monitoring

I have a requirement to develop an application which will monitor the usage of the phone cameras and record information about when/where a photo was taken. I am aware that this information is typically recorded in the image metadata but I have a need to add additional information to this and record it separately from the image.

In essence, I would like to know:

- Any time the camera is opened, closed, activated (brought to front), deactivated (user switches to another app)
- Any time the camera saes a file; either a photo or a video
- Know the above regardless of whether the camera was launched directly or via another app
- Know the above regardless of whether the caller used an intent or the camera APIs.

Are there good APIs to use for this? Is it possible to replace low-level interfaces to act as a man-in-the-middle? Is it possible from Java or would this necessarily be in C/C++?

At the moment my only solution would be to monitor the logs in a continuous service to identify everything I could from the above and implement a FileObserver to check for file creation/modification times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are there good APIs to use for this?

There are no APIs for this, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

> Is it possible to replace low-level interfaces to act as a man-in-the-middle?

On a rooted device, perhaps. In a custom ROM, definitely. In an ordinary Android device, no, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

> would be to monitor the logs in a continuous service to identify everything I could from the above

You have no access to logs, other than those generated by your own process, on Android 4.1+, except on rooted devices or from a custom ROM.

> and implement a FileObserver to check for file creation/modification times

There is no requirement for a camera app to store a file in a place for which you have filesystem access.

Comment: Is there a good place that summarises what an app can and cannot do? That goes over what permissions are privacy and security issues and what are not?

Comment: @magician11: "Is there a good place that summarises what an app can and cannot do?" -- I am not aware of any, sorry.